# How to unit test mergeMap in service call

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to unit test a service which contains a method which is calling two APIs using mergeMap.
I have written the test case but it only passes the first API call. I cannot figure out a way how this could work for both the API calls.

This is my `posts.service.ts`:

```
getRequest():Observable<any>{
   return this.httpClient.get<any>(`https://some-api/v1/get`).pipe(
      mergeMap(token=>this.httpClient.get<optout>(`https://another-api/v2/get`))
    )
  }
```

This is the `posts.service.spec.ts` file that I tried:

```
describe('PostsService', () => {

  let service: postsService;
  let httpController: HttpTestingController;
  let apiURL=environment.apiURL;

  let getTokenApi='http://https://some-api/v1/get';
  let getProductApi='https://another-api/v2/get';

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[HttpClientTestingModule,HttpClientModule],
      providers:[{provide:API_CONFIG_TOKEN,useValue:{usewsfApi:false}},postsService]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(postsService);
    httpController=TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should retrieve the products and token from API via GET', () => {
    const postsMock:optout={   
        "productsample": [     
          {     
            "privacyType": "val1",     
            "consented": false,    
          },{     
            "privacyType": "val2",     
            "consented": false,     
          },{  
            "privacyType": "val3",  
            "consented": true,
          }
        ]
    }

    service.getRequest().subscribe(posts=>{
      expect(posts).toEqual(postsMock);
    })

    const req=httpController.expectOne({
      method:'GET',
      url:getTokenApi
    });
  
    req.flush(postsMock);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you proceed to test the call inside `mergeMap`, you need to fix the following code which is causing your unit tests to run incorrectly:

The `it('should retrieve the products and token from API via GET', () => {` test runs synchronously, however the following `expect` invocations are run asynchronously:

```
service.getRequest().subscribe(posts=>{
  expect(posts).toEqual(postsMock);
})
```

This means that the unit test does not wait for the asynchronous code to finish running and concludes that the test has finished without giving these `expect` invocations a chance to run. Additionally there is a chance that they never run to begin with.

I would advise changing the unit test parameter to `(done) => {` and then adding the `done` callback after the `expect` like so:

```
service.getRequest().subscribe(posts=>{
  expect(posts).toEqual(postsMock);
  done();
})
```

Once the above is taken care of, all you need to do is repeat the `flush` implementation you have again for the `getProductApi` call with an appropriate return cargo.

This should then invoke the `service.getRequest().subscribe(` call and you should be able to assert the results. However, I can see that you are currently expecting the result to be `postsMock`, which given the actual code that you are testing is incorrect, as it should be the result of `mergeMap`.

Hopefully this leads you towards the right path!

Comment: sure will try :] Thanks @Ovidijus

Comment: Hi, if this solution helped you to achieve your goal, would you mind accepting it. Thankyou!